# Let local drush call remote drush with `bash` or `sh`

Tags: drush

I am trying to get database syncing with drush going. I installed drush on my webserver, but I only have the permission to run it with `bash` or `sh` before `drush`. (So with `./drush` I get `permission denied`)

It seems that my local drush calls the remote drush without `bash` or `sh`, so I get `permission denied` when I try `drush status` for my @bla.remote.

Is there a way to tell drush to use these commands or can you think of another way to bypass this problem?

Could I write an alias somewhere into drush?

Comment: Oh, you might just need to `chmod +x` your `drush` script -- but if that does not work, I describe how you can provide your own Drush wrapper below.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do something like this:

```
$aliases['myremotesite'] = array (
  'remote-host' => 'isp.example.com',
  'remote-user' => 'www-admin',
  'root' => '/srv/www/example.com/drupal',
  'uri' => 'http://example.com',
  'path-aliases' => array(
    '%drush-script' => '/home/www-admin/bin/my-drush',
  ),
);
```

Customize URIs, paths and sitenames to suit.  Then, create a 'bin' directory in your $HOME (if you don't already have one), and make yourself a 'my-drush' script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

bash drush $@
```

Once we commit https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/1595, you will be able to simplify the above by copying the drush.wrapper script to your remote site's Drupal root, and prefixing its call to the Drush launcher with `bash`.  That PR is close, but it's also Drush 8 only, so you might prefer making your own `my-drush` script, as shown above.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately with this script I have the same problem as with drush. I can only run it with `bash`. I've already tried messing with the permissions, but I can't fix it this way.

Comment: Well, while you could set `'%drush-script' => 'bash'` in your alias, there is no way for you to add `drush` as its new first parameter, so I think you're out of luck here.  Ask your webserver support staff if they can allow you to run scripts without `bash`, or if they have some other way that will allow you to set the executable bit successfully (SE Linux issue, maybe?).

Comment: I just contacted them and they wont give me the permissions :( Could I maybe alter my local drush in any way for this to work? Cause there I can do what I want.

Comment: Your hosting provider has disabled executable scripts, so you cannot solve your problem with scripts!  The best solution would be to switch to a more reasonable provider.  The only recourse you have currently is to write the above `bash drush $@` as a short "C" program, and point '%drush-script' to that.